# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' with Lazy Loading ListView flutter

Tags: flutter

I make list view to show data of user from Api and I make to this list Lazy Loading try to cut list each 10 user. But at first 10 user the list view work fine but when I try to move after 10 user I get this message:

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I try to add toString like this:

```
ListTile(title: Text((users[index]['name'].toString()))) ;
```

But when I add toString All List load at first time with out make Lazy Loading.

My Code:

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static int page = 0;
  ScrollController _sc = new ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  List users = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    this._getMoreData();
    super.initState();
    _sc.addListener(() {
      if (_sc.position.pixels == _sc.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _getMoreData();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Lazy Load Large List"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: _buildList(),
        ),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: users.length + 1,

      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index == users.length) {
          return _buildProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          return ListTile(title: Text((users[index]['name']))) ;

        }
      },
      controller: _sc,
    );
  }


  final int _limit = 15;
  Future _getMoreData() async {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      final String url = "*********************.php?=" + "&results=$_limit";
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

      print(url);

      List tList = [];
      var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (int i = 0; i < responsebody.length; i++) {
        tList.add(responsebody[i]);
        print(tList);

      }
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        users.addAll(tList);
        page++;
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Opacity(
          opacity: isLoading ? 1.0 : 00,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I don't know what is the error

thank you

Comment: Do you have the indication on which line this occur? Check the error stack and indicate the line concerned.

Comment: You have a `print(tList);` which should be replaced with `print(tList.toList()); `

Comment: Hi bro @Alaindeseine I was try make it  like (  users.addAll(tList.toList());) but still problem is not solved

Comment: Yes pro the problem in this line :ListTile(title: Text(users[index]['name'])) ; @Alaindeseine

Comment: Can you provide users data snippet?

Comment: You have extra parenthesis in ``Text((users[index]['name'])))  ``

Comment: @Alaindeseine yes bro / I save example data name in my db lilk that (I/flutter (26550): [test, ytr, treter, yrty, ytr, ytyr, ytry, tre, ytry, ytyr, tytr, ryyt, ytry, ytrytr, tyrt, ertret, yrtyr, ytryr]) all is string

Comment: @Alaindeseine I updated the question and uploaded a picture of the problem

Comment: I try this also Text((users[index]['name'])))  and not work

Comment: Are you shure that your PHP script return correct datas? Have you print response to verify what you get?

Comment: Why don't you test `response.statusCode` before processing data to be shure you don't try to process an arrer as it's datas?

Comment: Hi bro / if php have problem or response.statusCode have any problem also the first page not work but now  the first page is work as you can see in above image in question @Alaindeseine

Comment: Hi bro there are was two problem first one I was have number with string data and second problem  in keyword of limit in URL  @Alaindeseine thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the type of Users. Its mentioned just as a List. You can try

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [];
```

to first make sure that its a list of map to access the `['name']` from it. if it shows List<dynamic> then try

```
Text("${json.decode(users[index])['name']}"),
```

Comment: Hi pro / I try it but still problem not solved

Comment: Type of Users string + same times int  / you know like username ali6353 and same times ali just

Comment: that just example

Comment: I updated the question and uploaded a picture of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replace this line:

```
final String url = "*********************.php?=" + "&results=$_limit";
```

By this one:

```
final String url = "*********************.php?=&results=" + _limit.toString();
```

Comment: Hi bro / I try it not solved problem

Comment: Can you see here please/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313327/how-to-cut-data-by-lazy-loading-in-flutter

Comment: @MAl question removed!

Comment: Hello brother, I have updated and modified it, see here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316743/how-to-writing-url-of-lazy-loading-in-flutter